# Функция push_back с указателем на указатель в одномерном массиве

Tags: c++

Нужно реализовать функцию push_back при таком синтаксисе функции: то есть указатель на указатель в одномерном массиве.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
void push_back(T ** array, T buffer, int array_size)
{
   const int size = array_size + 1;
    T* inside_array = new T[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
        inside_array[i] = (*array)[i];
    inside_array[array_size] = buffer;
    if (array_size >= 100)
    {
        throw 1; 
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array_size;
    cout << "Размер массива: ";
    cin >> array_size;
    int* array = new int[array_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i + 1;
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    int buffer;
    cout << "\nДобавить элемент: ";
    cin >> buffer;
    try
    {
        push_back(&array, buffer, array_size);
    }
    catch (int e)
    { 
        cout << "ошибка №: " << e << endl;
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size + 1; i++) 
    {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема: программа не работает.

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы зачем-то создаёте новый массив, переносите в него старый, добавляете туда же новый элемент - и всё. Оригинальный массив никак не изменяется, а новый пропадает. Есть ещё много других странностей (например, работа с размером), но это уже мелочи на фоне бессмысленности основного алгоритма.

Answer (score 1):

Ну так внутри `push_back` нужно ведь еще не забыть освободить старый массив

```
delete [] *array;
```

и затем сделать

```
*array = inside_array;
```

т.е. перенаправить указатель на новый массив.

А сейчас вы просто зачем-то создаете какой-то новый массив и затем сразу забываете о нем - выкидываете его в утечку памяти.

Отдельно стоит заметить, что и значение размера массива может быть правильнее было бы передавать в функцию `push_back` по указателю/ссылке и там внутри функции модифицировать (увеличивать на единицу). Раз уж функция `push_back` ответственна за собственно добавление элемента в массив, то пусть она будет ответственна и за соответствующее изменение переменной, хранящей размер массива (даже если это изменение тривиально).

Comment: Спасибо огромное, заработало ) То есть добавить +1 к памяти в самой функции ?

Comment: То есть добавить +1 к памяти в самой функции ? И как правильно добавить?

Comment: @Дмитрий, вообще менять размер массива на 1 при каждом удалении/добавлении - плохая идея. Но это уже совсем другая история :)

Comment: @PinkTux я с вами согласен, просто преподаватель сказал так лабу оформить, как доп. задание )

Comment: Ну если в массив надо добавить 1 элемент, то понятно, что "живой" размер массива увеличится ровно на 1 элемент - тут никуда не денешься. А уж то, что память можно было бы переаллоцировать (т.е. увеличивать "сырой" размер массива) более крупными шагами, а не при каждом "чихе" - это верно. Но да, это уже другая история.